# Is it a bug that certain properties that may return nil in the Cocoa APIs are declared as implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Tags: cocoa, swift

While working with an array of NSRunningApplication(containing all running applications), I noticed my app crashing due directly accessing the bundleIdentifier property without first checking for nil. This is a bug that could have been entirely avoided without reading the documentation if the property was declared as a proper optional, because then the type system wouldn't have allowed me to use it without first unwrapping it.

This property is documented and declared like this in the swift header:

```
/* Indicates the CFBundleIdentifier of the application, 
   or nil if the application does not have an Info.plist. */
var bundleIdentifier: String! { get }
```

Is there any reason that this property is not declared as a proper optional?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_32 *"...  you should always check and unwrap an implicitly unwrapped optional yourself, unless you are sure that the value cannot be missing."* – I think it was a design decision between ease of use and safety to import all Objective-C types as implicitly unwrapped optionals.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin R stated, defining the return types as implicitly unwrapped optional is a design decision of Apple. Imagine you get an optional for every call of a Cocoa API. You just have to be as careful as you was with Objective-C as long there isn't an updated framework for Swift.